# How can I extends mongoose Model<T>?

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose

Using mongoose and typescript I want to create a BaseRepository where I can avoid some duplicated code, like create, list, update and delete.

So this is what I have:

*Model*

```
import mongoose, { Document, Schema } from 'mongoose';

export interface ILog extends Document {
    description: string;
}

const LogSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  description: { type: String, required: true, unique: true }
});

export default mongoose.model<ILog>('Log', LogSchema);
```

*Repository*

```
export class LogRepository extends BaseRepository<Log> {
  protected model = Log;
}
```

*BaseRepository*

```
import { Document, Model } from 'mongoose';

export abstract class BaseRepository<T extends Model<T>> {
  protected abstract model: T;

  public find (): Promise<T[]> {
    return this.model.find().exec();
  }

  public create (body: any): Promise<T> {
    const data = new T(body);
    return data.save();
  }

  public update (id: string, body: any): Promise<T | null> {
    return this.model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, body).exec();
  }

  public async delete (id: string): Promise<number | undefined> {
    const res = await this.model.deleteOne({ _id: id }).exec();
    return res.n;
  }
}
```

But at BaseRepository I'm getting `Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'Document'`;

Also, how can I do the new T (at create method)?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `new T()` because T is the type.  If `this.model` is the class, then what you want is to call `const data = new this.model(body);`

This mostly works:

```
export abstract class BaseRepository<T extends Document> {
  protected abstract model: Model<T>;

  public create (body: any): Promise<T> {
    const data = new this.model(body);
    return data.save();
  }
```

But I'm not sure what your `Log` type looks like.

Comment: `Log` it's the `export default mongoose.model<ILog>('Log', LogSchema);`

Comment: Now I'm getting `'Log' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Log'?ts(2749)`

Comment: I assumed `Log` was a type because you are using it as a type when you do `extends BaseRepository<Log>`.  The thing inside the brackets here needs to be a type.  This should work: `export class LogRepository extends BaseRepository<ILog> {
  protected model = Log;
}` because your model `Log` fulfills the needed type `Model<ILog>`.